# Behaviour of $u_{n}=u_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}+u_{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}+u_{\lfloor n/6\rfloor}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

I was looking at the following sequence:
$$\begin{cases}
u_0=1\\
\forall n \in \mathbb{N^*}, \quad u_{n}=u_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}+u_{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}+u_{\lfloor n/6\rfloor}
\end{cases}$$ and wanted to show that $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad u_n\leq 3(n+1)$$ I know a way to do this is to see that $u_{n+1}\leq u_n+3$ but I can't seem to easily prove that fact (case by case analysis should work, I guess).

I also wrote a Python script to check the first $1000000$ terms and found that the best bounding constant isn't $3$, but actually $C=\frac{169}{73}$. I read somewhere that you could find an explicit expression of $C$ in terms of $u_0$, but I can't figure out how. What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, I do not consider this question to be answered, as the second part about the constant $C$ has not been addressed.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the best bounding constant" ? The absolute best bounding constant for $\frac{a_n}{n}$ is known to be $3$ (by dromniscience's answer), and the asymptotic best bounding constant (aka limsup) for $\frac{a_n}{n}$ is known to be $\frac{12}{\log(432)}$ by Robert Israel's answer. What else is there to look for ? I think you're confused about this, and contrary to what you said, all the obvious questions have already been answered.

Comment: I did not understand why drominiscience's answer explains that the BEST bounding constant is 3. Secondly, my question adds that there should be an expression for $C$ in terms of $u_0$, that has not been addressed. Thanks!

Comment: Answer to 1st question : The inequality $\frac{u_n}{n}\leq 3$ becomes an equality when $n=1$, so the upper bound $3$ is best possible. Answer to 2nd question : if $(v_n)$ is the sequence with $v_0=1$ and $(u_n)$ is another sequence with $u_0\neq 1$, clearly $u_n=u_0v_n$, so the best constant for $(u_n)$ is simply $3u_0$.

Comment: I don't seem to be making myself clear. In the OP, I ask what is the optimal $C$ st $u_n\leq C(n**+1**)$, which is not $3$. Indeed, up until $1$ million, the best one is $169/73$ which happens for $n=72$. Your comment about linearity is clear indeed, but somehow I didn't see it, thanks. The natural follow up would then be, if we don't want the upper bound to be defined by the $C$, for example: if $u_0=2$, we can (clearly) say $u_n\leq 2C(n+1)$ OR $u_n\leq C'(n+2)$ for a new optimal constant $C'$ which in this case would be $993/217$ that occurs for $n=432$.

Comment: Why should $C$ and $C'$ be so? How to generalise? I hope you understand what I mean now, but thanks anyway.

Comment: What do your double stars mean ? If they mean "multiplied by an arbitrary constant", for any $C$ at all you can write $u_n\leq C(an+b)$ where $a=\frac{3}{C}, b=0$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I guess the double star means a try to make “$+1$” in a bold font.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yes, indeed! Sorry, I forgot that doesn't work inside of math mode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [OEIS sequence A007731](https://oeis.org/A007731).  This references a paper of P. Erdős, A. Hildebrand, A. Odlyzko, P. Pudaite and B. Reznick, [The asymptotic behavior of a family of sequences](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/%7Eodlyzko/doc/arch/sequence.family.pdf), Pacific J. Math., 126 (1987), pp. 227-241, according to which the limit of $u_n/n$ is $12/\log(432)$.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the link! Do you think they talk about the max of $u_n/n$ in the paper? Since it isn't increasing...

Comment: I just read to the end of the paper and, if I'm not mistaken, they do not tackle the problem of the optimal $C$. So thank you, but it doesn't answer the OP.

Comment: @Bcpicao Since $\tfrac {12}{\log 432}<\tfrac {169}{73}$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $\tfrac {u_n}{n+1}<\tfrac {169}{73}$ for each $n\ge N$. If using the results from the paper we can show that $N$ is not very big then the remaining cases $n\le N$ can be checked by a computer.

Comment: @AlexRavsky That is indeed a good point, although this article doesn't seem too permeable for me, if you could check that I would appreciate. Although, I admit, I was looking for an analytic solution. Check my comments on the original question. Thanks!

Comment: @Bcpicao An analytic solution can be rather complicated. But we can omit an analytic estimation of $N$ as follows. Put $C_0=\tfrac{169}{73}$. Suppose that a computer checked that for some natural $N’$ we have $u_n\le C_0n$ for all $N’\le n<6N’$. Then we have $u_n\le C_0n$ for all $n\ge N’$ (and thus $u_n\le C_0(n+1)$ for all $n$), so we are done. I expect $N’$ is not very large, maybe even $N’=73$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky According to my computations, $N'=74$ (because $u_n\leq \frac{995}{432}n$ for $n\geq 74$ ; this becomes an equality for $n=432$). You cannot have $N'=73$ because $u_{73}=u_{72}=169$

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply prove $\forall n\in\mathbb{N_+},\ u_n\leq3n$ by induction?

At least $u[1:6]$ satisfies this inequality.

Comment: $n=0$ does not work if you don't add the "$+1$". Then, as I said, it'll work for all $n$. Also, how would you go about proving the hereditary part?

Comment: This is why I emphasize that at least  $u[1:6]$ should be verified. If it holds for $u[1:6]$, for index which is greater than 6, $u[0]$ will never be used. Thus, the induction can be properly carried out. Prove it over $\mathbb{N_+}$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, could you please elaborate? Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Though $u[0]$ does not satisfies the inequality, it is no big deal. We will just skip this initial term and prove it for any $n > 0$. Without much effort, we have $u[1:6] = [3, 5, 7, 9, 9, 15]$. Thus, we conclude that if $1\leq n \leq 6$, $u[n] \leq 3n$.  What if $n > 6$? This time, $\lfloor n/6\rfloor \geq1$. By induction, $u[n]= u_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} + u_{\lfloor n/3\rfloor} + u_{\lfloor n/6\rfloor}\leq 3(\lfloor n/2\rfloor+\lfloor n/3\rfloor+\lfloor n/6\rfloor)\leq3n$.

Comment: Eventually, to sum it up, we could say that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_n \leq 3n + 1$. This time, we take $n = 0$ into consideration.

Comment: I am totally dumbstruck. This was exactly what I did but with the tiniest difference: taking as the recurrence hypothesis that $u_n\leq 3(n+1)$. This means that $u_{n+1}=u_{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}+u_{\lfloor (n+1)/3\rfloor}+u_{\lfloor (n+1)/6\rfloor}\leq 3(\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor+\lfloor (n+1)/3\rfloor+\lfloor (n+1)/6\rfloor+3)\leq 3(n+4)>3(n+2)$ which doesn't work! I don't understand the conceptual difference between the two. My looser hypothesis should work better, right?

Comment: Actually, it is a trick commonplace in the induction process - to tighten the bound you want to proof.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep that in mind! Any idea on how to prove that $u_{n+1}\leq u_n+3$?

Comment: Well, I run a python script, only to discover that counterexamples exist, even if n is sufficiently large(In my case, I checked it for every $n \leq 100,000,000$, and the two biggest counterexamples are $n = 90,699,263$ and  $n = 95,551,487$). I am afraid that it is untrue.

Comment: That makes sense! Some guy in a French forum "proved" it in a way I didn't understand, turns out he was wrong. How about the minimal value of $C$? Do you know how to find it?